# Moving to Azure hosting and how to choose session state, Database and server

Tags: asp.net, azure, session, azure-web-app-service, session-state

I am totally new to Azure and have been asked to move websites to Azure hosting.

Moving to Azure hosting do seems to an issue but problem seems to be with the asp.net session state, our website which are developed using asp.net 4.0 & MVC & some of the website are quite old developed few years back around 2013-2014.

My big worry is how to choose session state or third part session cache where we wont need to make any change in code other than to web.config file.

We so many article around it has created confusion.

I would appreciate best way we can migrate to azure hosting without making changes to code other than web.config file.

I looked at Azure Redis Cache but this also required to install `Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers` and changes to config file [link](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/running-kentico-on-microsoft-azure/storing-cache-and-session-state-data-in-azure-environment).

Does Azure provide MS SQL Database with build in support for SQL Session, so that we only need to make change to web.config file rather than installing packages using nuget etc..

This option of Microsoft blog seems to be the option can some config if this right & easy approach. but also at the comment user have posted few issue with this approach 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/11/28/asp-net-session-state-with-sql-server-in-memory-oltp/

Based on above let me give more details

- We use windows based dedicated server for hosting
- We use MS SQL SERVER Windows 2012 for database
- IIS 7.5
- and other software to managing website such as plesk
- We have website developed in asp.net webform based website running with framework 4.0 or 4.5
- We also have few asp.net MVC based website running on framework 4.5
- We use InProc default session state

Firstly, my big concerns are session state, i want to migrate to Azure without making any changes to code except changes to web.config is this possible?

Second we use MS SQL SERVER 2012 as database what is equivalent of same in Azure as in some page it refers database as [SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/#virtual-machines4) and some where as [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/) which creates confusion of this SQL Database or Azure database as i have red that these are two different things?

Third, let us say i choose Meb+Mobile--> App Service Standard Package (which comes with upto 10 instance) what are these instance? and will individual session always connect to same instance?

Forth: Database i have about 20 database one of them is about 6GB & other database are about 200MB-700MB which service should i use for database

- Single Database or Elastic?
- Can i create multiple database under elastic mode?
- Let us say if i choose "100 eDTUs: 10 GB included storage per pool, 200 DBs per pool, $0.20/hour" will i have total of 10GB space for all database in elastic pool and what is per pool and how many pools will i get in this option.

Fith:Disk Space, let us say i choose App Service "S2: 2 Cores(s), 3.5 GB RAM, 50 GB Storage, $0.200", is 50GB diskspace include OS or space allowcated to file which we upload?

I have asked too many question as i didnt had clarity from MS chat as they just passed links which can be confusing at time

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the Redis session state provider is a Nuget package, though you could *possibly* install it in another project and just throw the DLL in the app's bin folder. I have not tested this, so I can't know if it would actually work.

But another option for legacy apps is to keep ARR Affinity on in the App Service (if you are using them). This effectively sets a cookie on the client when they first connect so the load balancer will always connect them to the same instance, so in-memory session state works.

The problem with that is of course if the instance restarts for any reason, you lose the session state. Auto-scaling is also a bit of a problem.

Comment: Do you mean to say for `ARR Affinity ` if activate we dont need to do anything else and will it automatically connect to the same instance again or we have to use machinekey for this in web.config i remember few years back i had website hosted in server farm & i kept loosing session variable as i was not aware it was a server farm hosting, this was resolved by adding machinekey in webconfig which always connected the individual session to same instance/machine

Comment: Machine key solves one piece of the problem, since that needs to be the same across instances so that anything encrypted/signed using them is also valid for the other instances. But ARR Affinity *sort of* gets around that problem since it ensures that at least that user session in that browser will always hit the same instance, if it is available.

Comment: But it is not perfect, like I said, in-memory session state can be lost. This is true in on-prem web farms as well.

Comment: I think i can try both to check for some website which are basic website `ARR Affinity` as we dont store or use session variabel for critical thing. while redis coudl be using for other site which has traffic and may rely on session performance., Thanks

Comment: I am totally new to Azure so just trying to say as Microsoft chat was not much of a help as they passed be link to know more why i was trying to ask technical questions for clarity.

Comment: Stack Overflow is pretty good for questions like this, as long as you formulate your question well so there is a clear problem statement and that it is on-topic for SO.